# Problems with meshgrid with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to ask you some help regarding meshgrids.

I made an operation with grayscale images resulting in another image:

im = sqrt(im0^2 + im1^2).

Despite NOT being the main point of my question, here is the code used do load images and make the math operation (in any case the problem is the data generated):

```
dirname = '/users/files/images'

final = []
for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, fname))
    imarray = np.array(im)
    final.append(imarray)
    print(fname)
final = np.asarray(final)

im0=final[0,:,:]
im1=final[1,:,:]

im = np.sqrt(np.power(im0,2) + np.power(im1,2))

#mostra a figura
plt.figure(3, figsize=(5,5),dpi=120)
plt.title('imager sqrt(xˆ2 + yˆ2)')
plt.imshow(im,cmap='gray')
#plt.xlim(3600,3800)
#plt.ylim(1800,2000)
plt.minorticks_on()
#plt.grid(alpha=0.95,linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

This resulted in the following image (72x73 px), which ***is correct***:

[image: image made from the code above]

I would like to convert this image into a contour plot. To do so (or tried to do so), I used:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(im[0,:],im[:,0], sparse=True)
h = plt.contourf(im[0,:],im[:,0],im)
plt.show(h)
```

But the result is pretty weird:

[image]

Could somebody gimme some help on this matter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you read in a picture, I cannot run your code. So find an approximate example here:

```
nx, ny = 40, 20

ix = 0.1*nx*np.linspace(-1 ,1, nx)
iy = 0.1*ny*np.linspace(-1, 1, ny)

x, y = np.meshgrid(ix, iy, indexing='ij')

z = np.exp(-x**2 + -y**2)
plt.grid('equal')
plt.contourf(x,y,z)
plt.savefig('meshgrid.png'); plt.show()
```

[image]

Probably you can change your code as follows:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(im[0,:],im[:,0], sparse=True)
h = plt.contourf(xx,yy,im)
```